# How to disable rounding mode in integer field type?

Tags: forms, symfony, integer

Is there a way to disable rounding mode in an integer field type of Symfony2.0? When inserting a float I need to get an error, not a rounded integer.

Comment: How do you mean? Do you mean when you insert a new row into the database you want to catch that error or on your `form` submission? Also, are you using Doctrine for Entity Manager? By default, mysql will do the rounding, so we either need to create a Validation Class on your form or a custom handler in your Entity Model.

Comment: I mean on my form submission.
Got the Validation Class, thank you, just wanted to know if there was a way to avoid it :)

Comment: have you found any solution to prevent rounding integer type in symfony?

Comment: Yes, creating a validation class as @phpisuber01 sugested.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html

Comment: I have @Assert\Type(type="int", message="Amount must be an integer.") however floats still get through. Is there a way to stop rounding and generate an error?